# How I can get routes in a different package

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How I can get route "api/controller/roles". I need to get routes in a different package. Maybe using reflection or another method for this.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("roles")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddRoleAsync([FromBody] UserRoleRequest request)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Now I use:

```
var routeAttribute = controller.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(RouteAttribute));
    if (routeAttribute != null)
            newDocument.Url = ((RouteAttribute) routeAttribute).Template.Replace("[controller]", "").Replace("[Controller]", "")
                               + controller.Name.Replace("Controller", "")
                               + "/" + methodInfo.Name;
```

But I get "api/" without this attribute: [HttpPost("roles")]

Comment: The `MethodInfo` has `GetCustomAttribuetes()` as well.

Comment: @donggas90 But it always null :(

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem
you need use:

```
GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HttpMethodAttribute))
```

and you get string like this:

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPostAttribute("events")]
```